# JQUERY clickout side element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple menues on my page...

```
<div class="menu">
   <div>Menu header</div>
   <div>Menu content</div>// should hide on click outside .menu
</div>

<div class="menu">
   <div>Menu header</div>
   <div>Menu content</div>// should hide on click outside .menu
</div>
```

basically i need all the menu(s) to hide when a click is detected unless someone is clicking any of the menues it should hide any other menu(s) apart from the menu they clicked on.

I have seen a few that work but only if you have one menu on the page which is not exactly useful using stopPropagation as it may cancel any other necessary instructions;

any ideas would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
  var menu = $(evt.target).closest("div.menu");
  other = $("div.menu").not(menu).children(":last-child").hide();
  menu.children(":last-child").show();
});
```

Basically this listens to all [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) events. It determines if it happened inside a menu item. If it did it shows the content and it hides the content of the others. Otherwise it hides all the menu content.

Comment: It's hiding all the menues including the "menu header" which should not hide it should hide it's contents.

Comment: You are a life saver ... been looking for these 5 lines for a good 2 months lol :)